# Bash List files not matching an array of patterns

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

I am not that experienced with bash and I have a question.

I am trying to select some files (let's say ls for this example) that do not match a certain array o patterns.

I have files named Test,Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5,Test6,Test7,Test8,Test9,Test10 that I need to select in two groups.

1st group is Test5,Test6,Test7,Test8,Test9,Test10 which I can list by using:

```
ls -l T*@(5|6|7|8|9|10) or ls -l T*{5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

The 2nd group is the tricky one (for me) because of the Test & Test1 files. I am trying to invert the previous selection/listing.. or somehow select the rest.
I have tried several things with no luck:

```
ls -l T*[!5678910]
ls -l T*[!@(5|6|7|8|9|10)]
ls -l T*[!5][!6][!7][!8][!9][!10]
ls -l T*@(1|2|3|4|)
```

p.s: the actual filenames have extra characters after the number.

Comment: a suggestion, instead of `p.s: the actual filenames have extra characters after the number` please add examples that completely represent the problem at hand... also, all files have `Test` in common, not just starting `T` so even `Test!(5|6|7|8|9|10)` would work... such things would lead to solution specific to shown example.. it is easy to miss the last sentence

Comment: It turns out it was irrelevant, the solution works in my actual files (not the test example here). Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can inverse a pattern like this:

```
# enable extended glob, if disabled, it will not function
shopt -s extglob

# create our files
touch {Test,Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5,Test6,Test7,Test8,Test9,Test10}

# list files with matching pattern
ls -1 T*@(5|6|7|8|9|10)
Test10
Test5
Test6
Test7
Test8
Test9


# list files with NOT matching pattern
ls -1 T!(*@(5|6|7|8|9|10))
Test
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
```

Comment: did you try this? In bash i get "bash: !: event not found"

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!!
ls -1 T!(*@(5|6|7|8|9|10)) works as I wished!
I will try the other suggestions also.

Comment: @marek.jancuska: Of course I tested this in bash and copy/pasted results here. You need to enable `extglob` for this using `shopt -s extglob`

Comment: @anubhava - I see, added it to your answer, I think it will be more useful then (people may have extglob disabled)

Answer (score 2):

You may use an empty string as an option in the list:

```
ls -l Test*{,1,2,3,4}
```

[EDIT] But in general I don't see a way to do inverted match in bash alone. Also I see now that there may be other characters after numbers (I suppose non-numerical, or you would have no way to distinguish). I would use ´grep´ , possibly with ´-v´ flag for negation.

```
ls -1 |  grep -v "Test\(\(5\)\|\(6\)\|\(7\)\|\(8\)\\|\(9\)\|\(10\)\)"
```

Comment: OP asks: `I am trying to invert the previous selection/listing`

Comment: First one returns everything for me but the 2nd one works correctly!

Comment: well, it seems he doesn't need a general-case negation, but sure, a general case is better

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work with `*`, but it works with more specific patterns:

```
ls -l Test@(1|2|3|4|)
ls -l Test?([1-4])
ls -l T+([^0-9])?([1-4])
```

Comment: From what I understand the problem started with T*@(1|2|3|4|) that it returns all while Test@(1|2|3|4|) returns the correct (as also Test?([1-4])). It never occurred to me to would be so different.

Answer (score 1):

If `ls` is not your only acceptable command, you can also use `find` with `regex` to achieve your purpose:

- Create all test files:

  `touch Test{,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`
- Find your 1st group of files with `regex`:

  `find -type f -regex "\./Test\([5-9]\|10\)"`
- Reverse is simple, just add a `!` before option `-regex`:

  `find -type f ! -regex "\./Test\([5-9]\|10\)"`

It works on Linux Bash.